# Adding digits in list in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have sentence like "Q 000 1111 00001 0001 00 //SOME_STRING" I wanted to add except Q and //SOME_STRING in a List in Python in the Result only List contains 000 1111 00001 0001 00.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

data = "Q 000 1111 00001 0001 00 //SOME_STRING"

digits = re.findall(r"\b\d+\b",data)
```

Test

```
>>> re.findall(r"\b\d+\b","Q 000 1111 00001 0001 00 //SOME_STRING234zzzz")
['000', '1111', '00001', '0001', '00']
```

Comment: The result will be "['000', '1111', '00001', '0001', '00', '234']" without \b, which means word boundary. If your string will never contains digits, may be you don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def filter_digits(bar):
  return re.search("^\d+$", bar)

foo = "Q 000 1111 00001 0001 00 //SOME_STRING"
foo = foo.split(' ')
foo = filter(filter_digits, foo)
```